# A trapezium is inside a circle then find the radius of the circle ??

Tags: geometry, circles

There is a trapezium inside a circle with parallel side 6 and 10 cm with other sides are 4 and 4 cm. Find the radius of the circle. [image]

My attempt :- 
Imagine the center of the circle. The distance between the center and the vertices of the trapeze that touch the circle is r. Now imagine 2 triangles, where the hypotenuse is the radius and the legs is half the horizontal lines of the trapeze. After this I calculate the height of trapezium which come out to be $ \sqrt{12}$

Comment: we dont like to answer questions where no effort has been made to solve it whatsoever. Please show us what you tried. Hint: make use of the symmetry

Comment: See t have add my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Distance between parallel sides of trapezium $MN=\sqrt{4^2-2^2}=2\sqrt{3}$

Let $R$ be the radius of circle & $OM=x$

Using Pythagoras theorem in right $\Delta OMA$ $$R^2=x^2+5^2\iff R^2=x^2+25\tag 1$$

Similarly, using Pythagoras theorem in right $\Delta OND$
$$R^2=(x+2\sqrt3)^2+3^2\iff R^2=x^2+4x\sqrt3+21\tag2$$
subtracting (1) from (2) we get
$$0=4x\sqrt3-4\implies x=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$
setting value of $x$ in (1), we get
$$R=\sqrt{\frac13+25}=2\sqrt{\frac{19}{3}}\approx 5.033222957\ cm$$